# 1How to get HTTP_REFERER in symfony 1.0.17

Tags: symfony1, action, referer

I try to get referer in action.class.php

```
public function executeIndex()
  {
    $this->setTemplate('index');
    $this->referer = $this->getRequest()->getReferer();
  }
```

but without any result:( Anybody now how to solve this problem?

symfony version 1.0.17

Comment: solved `$this->getContext()->getRequest()->getReferer()`